# Trying to create secret in Azure Key Vault using Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to create a secret whenever a text file is uploaded to blob storage but I am getting the following error using the az command:

> [Warning] The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'az' command definition. If this command belongs to a module available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7.

This is my function

```
param([byte[]] $InputBlob, $TriggerMetadata)
Import-Module az
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName myakv -Name Mysecret -SecretValue abcde
```

And this is my requirements.psd1

```
@{
Az = '7.*'
}
```

Appreciate if anyone could give me some advice. Thank you!

Comment: You should be using the command Set-AzKeyVaultSecret,

Comment: Also, in requirements file, don't use single quote around `Az`

Comment: I am now getting "The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret' command definition." Shouldn't the az module already contain az.KeyVault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As functions are serverless code, in general, we don't have the Key vault we need to integrate it manually by adding a piece of code. Below is the sample code on integrating function app with Kay Vault
  [image]
- As suggested by [Anand-Sowmithiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran) You can use `Set-AzKeyVaultSecret` for creating key vault secret in azure functions.
- Here is the [document](https://dev.to/pwd9000/protect-secrets-in-azure-functions-using-key-vault-d2i) for Integrating Key Vault in Azure functions. You can refer to this for further information.

Comment: Thanks. The screenshot above seems to only be creating a keyvault and a function app which I have already done. Running Set-AzKeyVaultSecret gives me the error saying it is missing the module although I have already included the az module in requirements.psd1 file

Comment: Have you gone through the document which I gave you which has complete information on integrating key vault with function app.

Comment: Yes I have but the issue with missing module still is present and I am not sure what is wrong